# Re-entering China on a tourist visa

Tags: visas, china

I already have a 10-year multiple entry visa to China. The max duration of each stay is 90 days. Would I be allowed to stay for an entire year, as long as I leave the country and re-enter at least once every 90 days?

Comment: You could until the Chinese authorities decide you are 'residing' on a tourist visa.

Comment: Do you have a double entry or true multiple-entry ? @hippietrail might be interested to hear about this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are allowed to stay as long as you have an exit and entry out of the China every 90 days. 10-year multiple entry visa's do not have limitations on the number of entry and exit. You can leave for 1 day and come back without a problem.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Personal experience?

Comment: yup. personal experience for both myself and my friends. The 10-year visa is intended for people who frequently travel to and from China.